# Django 1.11 Custom User-model with Groups

Tags: python, django

I am trying to add a ForeignKey between my User(AbstractBaseUser)-model and the built in Group-model. My issue now is that I cannot create a superuser, as it requires to fill the group field with 'something'.

I have created a group through the shell, called admin with id 1. However, I can't find a way to create my superuser, and set the group to admin on creation ..

Here is **models.py** in my /accounts app:

```
from django.db import models
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
        BaseUserManager,
        AbstractBaseUser,
        Group
    )

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, group, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
            email = UserManager.normalize_email(email),
            password = password,
            group = group
        )
        user.set_password(password)
        user.save()
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, group, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email = UserManager.normalize_email(email),
            group = group
        )

        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save()
        return user


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    objects = UserManager()
    date_added = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True, db_index=True)

    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['group']

    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self):
        return self.email

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_perms(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    def is_staff(self):
        return self.is_admin
```

Whenever I run migrate.py createsuperuser, it asks for email, password and Group (Group ID). 
If I type `admin`, it gives this error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'admin'
```

if I type 1 (the id), it gives this error:

```
ValueError: Cannot assign "'1'": "User.group" must be a "Group" instance.
```

Comment: I also tried changing `group = group` to `group = Group.objects.get(id=group)` but that gives this error: `TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Group'`

Answer (score 3):

Meet the same problem.

Actually, `group` is `PermissionsMixin`'s attribution, so what you need to do is implement `PermissionsMixin` and `AbstractBaseUser`

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
```

Answer (score 0):

You could change

```
group = group
```

to

```
group = Group.objects.get(id=group)
```

Within your create_superuser def.

Then you can just use the group id (which is 1 in your case) which the superuser wizard expects.

In case you'll end up working with multiple instances, I would look into creating that group in a migration instead of through the shell (so it will automatically be there when you set up a new instance and run migrations).

Comment: Are you sure you only changed it in def create_superuser? Looking at the error you're giving in the comment on your original post it looks like you changed it on both create_user and create_superuser. I actually copied your code and just changed that one line and it works here.

Comment: I did, yes. Still no luck.

Comment: I just re-checked from scratch and it works for me. If you still have this problem, what python / django version is this on (and maybe you could also share a repo where this is on?).